# trying to tell user they entered the wrong value in java

Tags: java, mysql, crud

i can't figure out how to tell the user that there is "no such title found" when they go to search for a title. when i test it and type in a title from the database it shows the correct information:

```
Game Id:   2
Title:     Goldeneye 007
Rating:    T
Platform:  Nintendo 64
Developer: RockStar
```

but if i type in random information the output looks like this:

```
Game Id:   0
Title:     asdsdfdfg
Rating:    null
Platform:  null
Developer: null
```

i'm using a basic console application in java with mysql i have two layers.
my presentation layer:

```
private static Games SearchForGame() {
        Logic aref = new Logic();
        Games g = new Games();
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanline = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the game you wish to find:");
        g.setTitle(scanline.nextLine());
        aref.SearchGame(g);

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Game Id:   " + g.getGameId());
            System.out.println("Title:     " + g.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Rating:    " + g.getRating());
            System.out.println("Platform:  " + g.getPlatform());
            System.out.println("Developer: " + g.getDeveloper());

        return g;


    }
```

and a logic layer

```
public Games SearchGame(Games g) {

         try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
            String sql = "SELECT GameId,Title,Rating,Platform,Developer FROM games WHERE Title=?";
            java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, g.getTitle());
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){

            g.setGameId(rs.getInt("GameId"));        
            g.setTitle(rs.getString("Title"));
            g.setRating(rs.getString("Rating"));
            g.setPlatform(rs.getString("Platform"));
            g.setDeveloper(rs.getString("Developer"));
             }
             } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return g;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement?

```
if(g.getRating() != null /*or g.getGameId() == 0 or many other things*/) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Game Id:   " + g.getGameId());
    System.out.println("Title:     " + g.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Rating:    " + g.getRating());
    System.out.println("Platform:  " + g.getPlatform());
    System.out.println("Developer: " + g.getDeveloper());
} else {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("No such title found");
    //throw some sort of exception (and plan to catch it) so that you
    //can get out of this method without returning g full of null values
}

return g;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in many ways, will explain one here.

In SearchGame method use [isBeforeFirst()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst%28%29) method to check if you have any data at all.

```
if(!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()){
     return null;
 }
```

And in your `SearchForGame()` if the object is null, display a message.

```
if(g != null) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Game Id:   " + g.getGameId());
    System.out.println("Title:     " + g.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Rating:    " + g.getRating());
    System.out.println("Platform:  " + g.getPlatform());
    System.out.println("Developer: " + g.getDeveloper());
} else {
    System.out.println("No data found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking nulls is a bad form of flow control. You should consider a boolean result instead.

```
if(aref.SearchGame(g)) {
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Game Id:   " + g.getGameId());
   . . . 
else {
   System.out.println("No such title found"); 
}
```

Then in your logic, just do this:

```
public boolean SearchGame(Games g) {

   boolean found = false;
   try {

     [your sql select here]

     if (rs.next()) {

        [access result set]

        found = true;
     }
   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return found;
}
```

But an even better way is to return a list of Game instance and then check if that list is empty, like this.

```
List<Game> SearchGames(String title)
```

That's a good solid API, and you could use it like this:

```
List<Game> games = aref.SearchGames(title);
if(games.size() > 0) {
   Game g = games.get(0);     
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Game Id:   " + g.getGameId());
   . . . 
else {
   System.out.println("No such title found"); 
}
```

This also allows you to find multiple Games with similar titles if you wanted.